# Sonar scanner configuration issue

Tags: sonarqube

After running sonar scanner it throws error: ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.api.resources.Project.getAnalysisType()Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Project$AnalysisType;
        at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.SurefireSensor.shouldExecuteOnProject(SurefireSensor.java:48)

I have SonarQube 7.1 and sonar-scanner-4.0.0.1744-windows installed. Both of them added to path as environment variable till bin.

The sonar-scanner.properties file contains:

```
sonar.projectKey=Java_Project 
   sonar.projectName=Java_Project 
   sonar.projectVersion=1.0 
    sonar.sources=<path of the project path>/bin 
    sonar.java.binaries=.
```

---

It is throwing error. Will appreciate your help

Comment: Please add list of all installed SonarQube plugins with versions.

Comment: Maybe you should upgrade to the LTS version. The first three 7.x versions have some issues.